# How to fix cloned SharePoint 2010 App server window VM Mess up

Tags: sharepoint-server

Our system admin cloned our SharePoint 2010 App server window VM.

Now search service and user profile service is not working, don't know what else.

how we can fix this mess up.

Is it fine if restore old backup of config DB ( earlier to clone)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the farm may be the easiest way out. Restoring the Config/Admin databases isn't supported.

Comment: for our exisiting prod Farm we are facing issue, like we are not able to create user profile service, should we restore Config/Admin DB

Comment: Restoring those databases is not supported. If you "remove" the cloned server, you'll also take out your production SharePoint VM (since the object is identical).

Comment: Thank you Trevor for quick help, actually we have uninstalled sharepoint from the new box. May be this removal also effected our Farm. What should be the possible solution.

Comment: You can build a new server and join it to the farm. May not work since you may or may not have an existing farm member. Then you can just start the Service Instances on the new server.

Comment: We have already moved Central Admin on 2nd App Server as CA stopped working on 1st App Server 

For Search status page we have this error:

The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component 'c8323105-b7e2-4b38-9502-1a60fc1e7465' in search application 'FASTSSA' is in a good state and try again.

For User profile server, Synchronization Connection is disappeared and we are getting this error while creating, I have checked both Fore 

"MOSS MA not found"

Comment: Hi Trevor really appreciate your reply and help:

For our Search Service using Fast ( Fast indexing servers are separate ones) I am able to create Search App Service by using fast connector but when I am creating Query Service App pools then I am getting given below exception, can you please give any clue, why we are getting this error related to DB, I  tried to create service in two different times in morning and evening and getting same error:

Comment: Here we have error detail: 
Errors were encountered during the configuration of the Search Service Application. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Backup, file manipulation operations (such as ALTER DATABASE ADD FILE) and encryption changes on a database must be serialized. Reissue the statement after the 

current backup or file manipulation operation is completed. ALTER DATABASE statement failed. sp_dboption command failed.